# The term 'New-SPWebApplicationAppDomain' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying this tutorial [Enable apps in AAM or host-header environments for SharePoint 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNARt.png)
 but when I run the commandlet

```
New-SPWebApplicationAppDomain -AppDomain app.com -WebApplication site.com -Zone Internet -Port 4321**
```

in SharePoint 2013 Management Shell I get this error:

[image]

What might the problem be?

Comment: "The New-SPWebApplicationAppDoman cmdlet was first introduced in the March 2013 Public Update" - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn167722.aspx, what patch level are you on?

Comment: I downloaded and installed SharePoint 2013 last month. I don't know my patch level.

Comment: what you get when run this Get-SPWebApplicationAppDomain or get-Spfarm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add below code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
```

2) If that doesnt work, open SharePoint Management shell in admin mode.

[image]

Comment: still can't work!

Comment: check @RobertLindgren's comment. You need March 2013 PU update.